# Android: How to get session id using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to get the session id from the login panel and I am using Retrofit to make the request.

But when looking for the headers in the response I did't find any cookie set

And here is the request code:

```java
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.baseurl)).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
API api = retrofit.create(API.class);

Call<ResponseBody> call = api.loginhtml(et_user.getText().toString(), et_pass.getText().toString());
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        try {
            String head = String.valueOf(response.headers());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using this code you can have the session

```
response.headers().get("Set-Cookie")
```